# How to enqueue script before jQuery?

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I want to register and enqueue RequireJS before jQuery so that jQuery finds out RequireJS and register itself as the AMD module. How to achieve this?

Comment: I deleted my answer, after a quick search on this site afterwards and found out that @bonger had posted the same idea before here couple of years ago, that I had even already upvoted ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That's a mf hack. I will try it if my idea of unregistering jquery and registering it again with dependency on requirejs wont work. `wp_deregister_script('jquery');wp_register_script('requirejs');wp_register_script('jquery');`

Answer (score 0):

#### If I understood you correctly:

This might help you out:  [Using requirejs with wordpress](http://kaidez.com/requirejs-wordpress/)

#### If you are just trying to enqueue requirejs with jquery:

Look at this documentation: [Wordpress Enqueue Scripts Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#scripts)

So in your case it would look something like this:

`wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'PATH TO YOUR REQUIREJS FILE', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);`

Comment: I prefer help from more readable people with an open mind that will easily guess what the author meant.